# How do I add a where clause <> 0 for case statement in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, case-statement

I have a case statement where I am trying to add a where clause <> 0 for the case statement . However, I am not able to do as the error is saying the column name is not existed. This is the current code:

```
SELECT *,

CASE 
when A.TestValue is null then 
B.Collected
when B.Collected is null then 
A.TestValue
END
as Actual_Value 

FROM test_Table
where Actual_Value <> 0
```

Comment: case *expression* [and probably you want `coalesce()`]

Comment: can we add like this in where statement 
CASE 
when A.TestValue is null then 
B.Collected
when B.Collected is null then 
A.TestValue
END <> 0

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE 
when A.TestValue is null then B.Collected 
when B.Collected is null then A.TestValue 
END <> 0
```